# Decrypt SD Card Files Encrypted by Samsung Note 8

Tags: encryption

Few months ago I encrypted my Micro SD card on my Samsung Note 8 for security purposes, and 2 days back the phone overheated and asked me to turn off. After awhile I was trying to turn it on but got no luck. I brought the phone in the Samsung Service Centre and they fixed it by replacing the motherboard. And now the problem is, of course, I didn't get any chance to decrypt the SD card and now I cannot decrypt it because the phone kept telling to me that I have to use the same phone I used for encryption. I have tried a solution from this (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116750/how-to-decrypt-a-microsd-card-after-a-factory-reset-of-the-device-used-to-encryp) but no luck. Where I copied the encrypted files on my PC then format-encrypt-copyfiles... etc... Or maybe because the guys uses S5 here and I have Note 8. Whew! I really don't know what to do. I need some important documents in that SD card and even Samsung cannot give any solution about my problem. Hope you guys can give me some solutions. Apologies to all because I know that this issue has been asked here many times but I cannot comment in that so I've decided to make a new one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did Samsung copy your user data from the old mainboard to the new mainboard? If not the encryption keys are AFAIK lost and your data can not be decrypted.

Comment: They did not. Is it possible?

Comment: The purpose of cryptography like AES is to make it impossible to decrypt data without having the key. The key was in your user data therefore the encrypted data can no longer be decrypted. Breaking an encryption like AES (if AES and key derivation was implemented correctly) takes several thousand years. Therefore consider your data lost - start using backup and synchronization Apps in case you have important data on the sd-card.

Comment: Yes. Data got lost.. OMG.. This is life... What to do...